# How to Update uitableview from CloudKit using discoverAllIdentities

Tags: ios, multithreading, uitableview, swift3, cloudkit

So, I am new to cloudKit and to working with multiple threads in general, which I think is the source of the problem here, so if I simply need to research more, please just comment so and I will take that to heart.

Here is my question:

I am working in Swift 3 Xcode 8.1

I have in my view controller this variable:

```
var contactsNearby: [String:CLLocation]?
```

Then at the end of ViewDidLoad I call one of my view controllers methods let's call it:

```
populateContactsNearby()
```

inside that method I call:

```
container.discoverAllIdentities(completionHandler: { (identities, error) in

   for userIdentity in identities! {

      self.container.publicCloudDatabase.fetch(withRecordID: userIdentity.userRecordID!, completionHandler: { (userRecord, error) in

  let contactsLocation = userRecord?.object(forKey: "currentLocation")


    if self.closeEnough(self.myLocation!, contactLocation: contactsLocation as! CLLocation) {

       var contactsName = ""

       contactsFirstName = userIdentity.nameComponents?.givenName


      if contactsName != "" && contactsLocation != nil {

       self.contactsNearby?["\(contactsName)"] = contactsLocation as? CLLocation

  }

}

})
}
})
}
```

I apologize if I am missing or have an extra bracket somewhere. I have omitted some error checking code and so forth in order to get this down to bare-bones. So the goal of all that is to populate my contactsNearby Dictionary with data from CloudKit. A name as the key a location as the value. I want to use that data to populate a tableview. In the above code, the call to closeEnough is a call to another one of my view controllers methods to check if the contact from CloudKit has a location close enough to my user to be relevant to the apps purposes. Also myLocation is a variable that is populated before the segue. It holds the CLLocation of the app users current location.

The Problem:

The if statement:

```
if contactsName != "" && contactsLocation != nil { }
```

Appears to succeed. But my view controllers variable:

```
var contactsNearby: [String:CLLocation]?
```

Is never populated and I know there is data available in cloudKit.

If it's relevant here is some test code that I have in cellForRowAtIndexPath right now:

```
let contact = self.contactsNearby?.popFirst()

let name = contact?.key

if name != nil {

cell.textLabel?.text = name

}else {
cell.textLabel?.text = "nothing was there"
}
```

My rows alway populate with "nothing was there". I have seen answers where people have done CKQueries to update the UI, but in those answers, the user built the query themselves. That seems different from using a CloudKit function like discoverAllIdentities.

I have tried to be as specific as possible in asking this question. If this question could be improved please let me know. I think it's a question that could benefit the community.

Comment: You have an asynchronous call inside a `for` loop, so that isn't going to work very well. You need to use something like a dispatch group to wait for all of the asynchronous operations to complete and then you can invoke a closure to pass the data back to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I need to do some more testing, but I think I got it working. Thank you Paulw11 for your comment. It got me on the right track.

As it turns out there were 2 problems.

**First**, as pointed out I have an asynchronous call inside a for loop. As recommended, I used a dispatchGroup.

Inside the cloudKit call to `discoverAllIdentities` I declared a dispatchGroup, kind of like so:

```
var icloudDispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
```

Then just inside the for loop that is going to make an async call, I enter the dispatchGroup:

```
icloudDispatchGroup.enter()
```

Then just before the end of the `publicCloudDatabase.fetch` completion handler I call:

```
icloudDispatchGroup.leave()
```

and

```
icloudDispatchGroup.wait()
```

Which, I believe, I'm still new to this remember, ends the dispatchGroup and causes the current thread to wait until that dispatchGroup finishes before allowing the current thread to continue.

The Above took care of the multithreading issue, but my `contactsNearby[String:CLLocation]?` Dictionary was still not being populated.

Which leads me to the **2nd** problem

At the top of my view controller I declared my Dictionary:

```
var contactsNearby: [String: CLLocation]?
```

This declared a dictionary, but does not initialize it, which I don't think I fully realized, so when I attempted to populate it:

```
self.contactsNearby?["\(contactsName)"] = contactsLocation as? CLLocation
```

It quietly failed because it is optional and returned `nil`

So, in `viewDidLoad` before I even call `populateContactsNearby` I initialize the dictionary:

```
contactsNearby = [String:CLLocation]()
```

This does not make it cease to be an optional, which Swift being strongly typed would not allow, but merely initializes contactsNearby as an optional empty Dictionary.

At least, that is my understanding of what is going on. If anyone has a more elegant solution, I am always trying to improve.

In case you are wondering how I then update the UI, I do so with a property observer on the contactsNearby Dictionary. So the declaration of the dictionary at the top of the view controller looks like this:

```
var contactsNearby: [String: CLLocation]? {

didSet {

if (contactsNearby?.isEmpty)! || contactsNearby == nil {

return

}else{
DispatchQueue.main.sync {
self.nearbyTableView.reloadData()
}
}

}

}
```

I suppose I didn't really need to check for empty and nil. So then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I have something kind of like so:

```
let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "nearbyCell", for: indexPath)

if contactsNearby?.isEmpty == false {

let contact = contactsNearby?.popFirst()

cell.textLabel?.text = contact?.key

}else {

cell.textLabel?.text = "Some Placeholder Text Here"

}
return cell
```

If anyone sees an error in my thinking or sees any of this heading for disaster, feel free to let me know. I still have a lot of testing to do, but I wanted to get back here and let you know what I have found.